# What is the difference between abstract index notation and Ricci index notation?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading Straumann's GR text and he talks about the difference between abstract index notation and Ricci index notation very briefly. So I read the wiki article, but that did not help much. Say we have the Ricci tensor and two vectors. What does the expression $R_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu$ mean in the two index notations? Is contraction not the same thing as summation over an index pair (this is what I was led to believe in undergrad and not-so-mathematically-rigorous grad texts).

Comment: It sounds like you are asking "please explain the differences between abstract and Ricci notation," and not your title question. You might consider changing the title, then. Regards

Answer (score 9):

Ricci calculus explicitly works with components with respect to a basis.  Abstract index notation has the same look but means something very different:  the indices are merely placeholders, signifying whether the arguments of tensors are vectors or covectors.

In Ricci calculus, for instance, the expression $K_{ab}$ would mean $K(e_a, e_b)$, where $e_a, e_b$ are basis vectors.  For any particular $a, b$ this is a number.  For the full range of indices, this is an indexed collection of values.

In abstract index notation, $K_{ab}$ means a tensor $K$ that is a function of two vectors: $K(\text{vector}, \text{vector})$.

One hangup with this idea is that it's less clear what's going on when you do a contraction: in abstract index notation, you're no longer summing over bases, so it takes a little more thought to realize what's going on.  In that sense, the abstract notation for a contraction should be understood as corresponding to a more complicated mathematical operation that merely agrees with what you would get if you were to break into components and compute a trace.  In particular: one way to compute a contraction is to differentiate with respect to an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this as a **quadratic form** where you are using the components of $u$, which are $u^{\mu}$, and the components of a matrix $R_{\mu\nu}$.